# Merging an old HG repository into a newer Git repository

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

So I have an old, old Mercurial repository, in which most initial development was done.

Then, the project was published, the repository was forgotten, and the next webmaster took over by editing the files directly.

Eventually this was moved to a (new) Git repository, and all recent changes are now on there.

Now I want to move the newer Git repository and sort of place it on top of the old Mercurial repository, making the whole thing into a Git repository with all commits still intact. How do I do this? (The end of the old repository and the beginning of the new repository are not the same, due to the off-version-control changes)

I have no experience whatsoever with Mercurial, but reasonable experience with Git. This is all on BitBucket.

Edit: I think I need Git rebase, but I'm not sure how to use it, let alone link it with Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Since the repo is already published, there really isn't a way to do that.

Git comes with a python script to convert hg repos to git, called `hg-to-git.py` (usually installed as `/usr/share/git/hg-to-git/hg-to-git.py`)

First commit any uncommited changes in your hg repo, then:

```
# this will create a .git folder in your old hg repo, leaves .hg untouched
$ python2 /usr/share/git/hg-to-git/hg-to-git.py $PATH_TO_REPO
$ cd your-git-repo
$ git remote add hg-repo $PATH_TO_REPO && git remote update

# create an orphaned empty branch, repeat for each hg branch name.
$ git checkout --orphan original && git rm -rf . 
$ git merge hg/master
```

Comment: By "published" I think I used some special word that I didn't mean to use. I will try your solution. In a copy.